# npm ERR! help pls someone

Tags: node.js, json, npm

so in my folder, I created a notepad file that is named "package.json"
in that folder, I typed

```
{
“name”: “Bot”,
“version”: “1.0.0”,
“description”: “My First Discord bot”,
“main”: “bot.js”,
“author”: “acezx”,
“dependencies”: {}
}
```

and then when I try to npm install discord.io winston -save.
this happens:

```
npm ERR! code EJSONPARSE
npm ERR! path C:\Code programs\Discord Bot/package.json
npm ERR! JSON.parse Unexpected token "“" (0x201C) in JSON at position 3 while parsing near "{\r\n“name”: “Bot”,\r\n“ver..."
npm ERR! JSON.parse Failed to parse JSON data.
npm ERR! JSON.parse Note: package.json must be actual JSON, not just JavaScript.
```

Comment: I believe `“` should be `"`

Comment: Smart quotes are not allowed in JSON. You need to use regular double quotes `"`

Comment: The takeaway here is that a word processor is not a development tool.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you're using a proper IDE or non-rich text editor so that you get regular double quotes and note "Smart" quotes. See the snippet below which should work for you:

```
{
    "name": "Bot",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "description": "My First Discord bot",
    "main": "bot.js",
    "author": "acezx",
    "dependencies": {}
}
```

Also, see below for a list of possible IDE's you can use:

**Integrated Development Environments (IDEs):**

- ***[FREE]*** Notepad++ - https://notepad-plus-plus.org/downloads/
- ***[FREE]*** Visual Studio Code - https://code.visualstudio.com/
- ***[PAID + Free Trial]*** WebStorm - https://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/